# WebTable Handling in C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to click on send test link in the column against a particular contact in the adjacent column. Could you please let me know how my XPath would be in that case. 
[image: Webtable]

```html
<td><a href="javascript:;" class="faded send_test" data-contact-id="8589955306"
    title="This will send you an email with this contact's details">Send test</a></td>
<td onclick="editDetails(&quot;8589955306&quot;);">QaAutomationF3&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: <tr class="contact_row">
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="8589994011" id="strContactChecked_8589994011" class="uncheckbox">
                    </td><td><a href="javascript:;" class="faded send_test" data-contact-id="8589994011" title="This will send you an email with this contact's details">Send test</a></td> <tdonclick="editDetails(8589994011);"> mary@test.vuturevx.com&nbsp;
              </td>

Comment: Please post the relevant html, the one you provided doesn't match the elements you marked.

Comment: <td><a href="javascript:;" class="faded send_test" data-contact-id="8589955306" title="This will send you an email with this contact's details">Send test</a></td>
<td onclick="editDetails(&quot;8589955306&quot;);">QaAutomationF3&nbsp;</td>

Comment: @Melebius, I did try to edit but the code is not appearing after i save the edits

Comment: Since you haven’t applied the code formatting… By the way, @Guy had [done it for you](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48521449/2) already. Please check your edits in the preview window before posting.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the *send test* link, you can write a function as _click_Send_test()_  as follows :

```
public void click_Send_test(String emailID)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='contact_row']//td[.='" + emailID + "']//preceding::td[1]/a[@class='faded send_test']")).click();
}
```

From your `main()` or `@test` annotation Class, call the function `click_Send_test()` with the *emailID* as an argument for whom you want to `click()` on *send test* link as follows :

```
click_Send_test("mary@test.vuturevx.com");
```